# How to find value in multiple different array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 arrays and I want to find a value in them. It runs well in the first arr. Somebody tell me, what's wrong.

```js
var find = 2;
var value = 0;

var aray1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var aray2 = [5, 6, 7, 8];
var aray3 = [9, 10, 11, 12];
for (var i = 0; i < 1. length; i++) {

  if (aray1[i] == find) {
    value = aray1[i];
    break;
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < aray2.length; j++) {

    if (aray2[j] == find) {
      value = aray2[j];
    }
    break;
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < aray3.length; k++) {

    if (aray3[k] == find) {
      value = aray3[k];
    }
    break;
  }

}
```

If "find" in aray1 do well but "find" in aray2 and aray3 not found !

Comment: Numbers are not allowed to begin a variable name. Also, no Java or GAS involved in the question.

Comment: From the [`java` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info): "*Java (**not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS**) ...*". From the [`javascript` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*JavaScript (**not to be confused with Java**) ...*"

Comment: I'm sory ! I am a new participant. I had adit

Comment: Thanks @KuldeepBhimte edit for me !

Answer (score 2):

If you format your code nicer, you'll see that the second and third for-loop are inside the first one -- you'll probably want to do them one after the other.

Also, you are just setting `value` to the value of `find` if it's found on any of the arrays -- you won't know where it was found first. What are you trying to accomplish here in the first place?

Also, don't name your variables with numbers -- it's not allowed by the specification. Names should start with a letter.